# On the ninth bar in Bach's BWV 940

Tags: piano, j-s-bach

This is bar 9 in J.S.Bach's BWV 940 in the Henle edition, which is in common time:

[image]

Is the initial upper D in the bass staff too long?

Comment: No.  Why do you think it might be?

Comment: Because there appears to be 5 voices on beat two?

Comment: @ElementsinSpace and three on beat 3.  The problem is with the rests, not the note lengths.  Or indeed with the assumption that there should be a constant number of voices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Henle specialise in urtext editions.   Perhaps the notation was Bach's fault.  I agree that it's technically 'wrong' and, more importantly, difficult to read.  The impression is clearly that the lower stave contains two voices, and the higher one doesn't add up!

Here's a version with more meticulous part-writing.

[image]

And another.  Both from IMSLP.

[image]

Comment: Ah, the second one is what I was playing (trying to play, really... )

Comment: The first one decided that there is a fifth voice?

Comment: Yes.  And no reason why it shouldn't, this is keyboard writing, not ACTUAL voices.